# Strange careers spam message

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, spam

I recently received the following message on Careers:

> Dear Applicant,
>
> Your resume has been reviewed by our HR Department for the position
>   and we believe you are capable of handling this position based on your
>   resume. Your details has been forwarded to Mr Michael Lens (Hiring
>   Manager). He would be conducting an online interview with you to
>   discuss the Job Details, Pay Scale and Benefits,etc.
>
> positions available are Data Entry Clerk,Administrative
>   Assistant,Accounting clerk, Sales manager and customer service. You
>   are to set up a screen name with yahoo instant messenger at
>   (messenger.yahoo.com) and add up the company Hiring Manager's yahoo
>   screen name (*redacted*) and instant message Him for an
>   immediate online interview/briefing exercise.
>
> Interview starts ASAP, you are to be available on yahoo messenger at
>   this time for the job briefing and interview,your swift and timely
>   response matters a lot to this position as the job starts ASAP. I wish
>   you best of luck.
>
> Regards Head of Operation of Catapult Design.

This seems like a fairly obvious spam post but I can't see how to mark/report it as such??

The person clearly did not read my resume because my skill set is completely orthogonal to any of the available positions and regardless who could possibly take seriously a request for an immediate interview via Yahoo Messenger?!

Comment: I would totally respond to an interview with the "Head of Catapult Design".

Comment: Yeah, no one uses Yahoo Messenger anymore! Google Talk/Hangout is the way to go!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks Rob! Someone else alerted us to this a little earlier today, and we terminated this search subscription about half an hour ago.

**edit** in answer to @RobV's question in the comments, either a meta post or an email to careers at stackoverflow dot com works if you want to report a spammy employer message

Comment: Is there a preferred way to report spam of this sort to SO?